# which controller or processor is suitable for interfacing the HD camera using usb or any other protocol?

Tags: camera, embedded, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, microprocessors

I need a suggestion for selecting a processor or controller.

I need to capture the photos from HD camera and these captured photos will be send to the web for further processing(over a WIFI module).

So what designing aspects should I consider while choosing between processor and controller ?

Can controller full fill my requirement as per mentioned above ?

Please let me know if is there any guide,documents or links are available.

Any help on this case would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth

Comment: Tool etc recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: define the minimum requirements and see what solutions will or wont work.

Comment: In my scenario one capture button is interfaced with processor or  controller. when i will press these button image will captured from the hd camera (Min 5-Megapixal)and these image will send to the server for further process.

Comment: Take a look at http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface